# How to draw something or write inside EditText Box using a finger but not with keyboard?

Tags: android, android-edittext, gesture, touch-event, ontouchlistener

[image]

In first case : When edittext box is clicked, should open a screen with white color background. In that screen, I would like to draw or write something without using a keyboard. It looks similarly like MS paint but using a finger should achieve this! Once after I completed (writing or drawing) then it should be able to paste the screen (which has user handwriting or drawings) inside edittext box.

So when I see Edittext box, the image (that is screen) will be there with a particular users handwriting. If the screen (similar to MS -paint screen) might looks bigger so via app should be able to minimize or convert the screen as a smaller screen (ie. finally converted as a Image which has users own handwriting or drawings) that fits exactly inside edittext box!

How can I achieve this? Can I achieve this by using Gestures or Canvas?

In Second case: I would like to know what are the possibilities available to display a screen with background color or background image (For an example, I can draw rectangle margins or insert greeting card borders (left, right, top and bottom side corners by cropping and inserting a picture) inside a screen so at middle of the screen, the space will be available to allow the user to write some text like "Happy Birthday" or "Good luck" so on..

[image: Can refer this Image!] [image: Happy Birthday wishes screen]

The writing or drawings should be done using a finger! How can I achieve this and what are the ideas and possibilities to do this via android app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want some handwriting recognition library to integrate with your app. Try finding  out a few existing libraries which you can use on android.

Answer (score 1):

That's simply not possible with the current EditText.

You will have to create your own widget.